# How to give users access to internal directory in android

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, internal

I am using Android studio... I want to give access of 1 specific directory to users... Internal directory... 
Is it possible to set a path using environment..Please help

```
String path= //if possible the environment
```

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what "give access of 1 specific directory to users" means. Also, please explain what "set a path using environment" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean I want to give a user for my application access to the internal
directory for eg-_@drawable_ which they can browse through..If it is an image, I want them to be able to view them like a gallery.& by the set of path i just mean i want an environment for the String path..Hope you could help

Comment: "the internal directory for eg-@drawable" -- that is not a directory on the device. It is only a directory on your development machine.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am aware..That is why i am asking can i make a raw folder which users can access?..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/" + filename);
```

will return a file in the internal directory.

Use this to get your path:

```
String path = context.getFilesdir();
System.out.println("Internal directory path: " + path);
```

If your class extends the `Activity` try:

```
String path = this.getFilesdir();
System.out.println("Internal directory path: " + path);
```

Comment: Thanks @Spectre I will try it and let you know if it works

Comment: It will! :) No prob

Comment: It's showing an error for getFilesDir() cannot be referenced from a static context & that variable file is never used

Comment: Don't use Context.getFilesDir(). You should get your context from somewhere. Your activity is a context too. Please show me your whole file with code, past in on pastebin.com or something.

Comment: It's a lot of code..I guess this part will be enough
right now i have
......................................................
String path=Environment.externaldirectory().tostring()+"/filename"
/**It was earlier for a existent file on sd card i want to change it to a internal one..If not able to answer no problem & thanks**/
.......................................................

Comment: This will return your external directory (SD card etc). If you want an APP directory (internal files, protected) you should use my method. The only thing you need to get is context. Please show me at least your class name, what it extends and it's constructor.

Comment: Just give me a minute & I appreciate it

Comment: on MainActivity.java i have created a dir named data...It has files
Intent is ImageIntent..i have a listview also..its not related but just in case (imagelistview)

Comment: Try this: String path = this.getFilesdir(); (I edited the answer above)

Comment: I am so sorry i am new to this as you may have understood, Can you tell me the exact code i can enter as the directory name "data" has not been used and i have no clue if the file can be used..by S.OPln as it will only display it.

Comment: I'll try giving you all aspects
my package name is
com.example.anonymous.filexp
my directory name name=data
The files i want users to operate = png jpg,html,and such files
`my activity names are- activity_main.xml,listview.xml
I Have a textview=Folder
String KEY_TEXTPSS="TEXTPSS"static final int Custom_ialog
Arraylis=filelist
array adapterstring= diretorylist
path=String path=Environment.externaldirectory().tostring()+"/filename"
ListView =dialoglist`
..I guess that's all i have

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following for the internal storage:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(mContext);
File fileDownloadFolder = cw.getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

File file = new File(fileDownloadFolder.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ filename);
```

in this example this return a file called `filename` inside the folder Downloads in the App folder in the internal storage.

And for the external storage use:

```
File fileDownloadFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(fileDownloadFolder.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ filename);
```